# ¿Por qué puedo declarar y sumar variables en C que desbordan los valores permitidos?

Tags: c, variables

Tengo una pregunta que me está dejando un poco confuso. Estoy utilizando el programa Code::Blocks para programar en C.

El código de mi ejercicio es muy simple, solamente declaro variables y muestro sus valores. El caso es que creo que tengo el código bien, pero el compilador me permite pasarme de los límites de valores permitidos por las variables declaradas. 
He añadido una suma al código en última instancia para ver si me saltaba un error de desbordamiento pero no ha ocurrido.

Este por ejemplo es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //unsigned short   8 bits (1 byte):  0 a 255
    unsigned short talla_pie = 38;

    //char  8 bits (1 byte):  -128 a 127
    //podemos imprimir la letra correspondiente al código ASCII del valor almecaenado en este variable
    unsigned char letraA = 65;

    //unsined int  16 bits (2 bytes):  0 a 65535
    unsigned int numero_habitantes_Zamora = 65362;

    //int  16 bits (2 bytes):   -32768 a 32767
    int numero_habitantes_Madrid = 3223334;
    int total_habitantes_Madrid_Zamora = 0;

    printf("Mi n%cmero de pie es %hu", 163, talla_pie);
    printf("\nEl valor 65 en el codigo ASCII pertenece a la letra %c", letraA);
    printf("\nEl n%cmero de habitantes de Zamora es %u", 163, numero_habitantes_Zamora);
    printf("\nEl n%cmero de habitantes de Madrid es %d", 163, numero_habitantes_Madrid);
    total_habitantes_Madrid_Zamora = numero_habitantes_Zamora + numero_habitantes_Madrid;
    printf("\nMadrid y Zamora suman un total de %d habitantes", total_habitantes_Madrid_Zamora);
    return 0;
}
```

¿Alguien me puede explicar por qué ocurre esto o si realmente estoy equivocado en mi idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En C, el tamaño de los tipos **dependen de la plataforma**. Para estar seguros, debemos usar la instrucción `sizeof( )`:

```
//char  8 bits (1 byte):  -128 a 127
printf( "%zu", sizeof( char ) );
```

> 1

Este si era correcto. De hecho, todos los demas **usan el tamaño de `char` como base**. Es decir, un tamaño de `2` **no significa** *2 bytes*; significa *2 char* o *el doble de un char*.

Sigamos:

```
//unsigned short   8 bits (1 byte):  0 a 255
printf( "%zu", sizeof( short ) );
```

> 2

```
//unsined int  16 bits (2 bytes):  0 a 65535
printf( "%zu", sizeof( int ) );
```

> 4

Ya vemos que tus suposiciones sobre tamaños estaban *un poco* equivocadas (al menos para mi plataforma).

> #### He añadido una suma al código en última instancia para ver si me saltaba un error de desbordamiento pero no ha ocurrido.

Eso es ... complicado. En operaciones con números **con signo**, el estandar dicta que el *overflow* es un **comportamiento indefinido**. Lo que ocurre si el resultado *se pasa* del tamaño del tipo puede variar entre máquinas, entre compiladores ... e incluso entre distintas operaciones en un mismo código. Puede provocarse un error ... o puede no pasar nada y que obtengas un resultado incorrecto.

Otra cosa es el *overflow* en datos `unsigned`. En este caso, el estandar indica que **no se produce error** ... así que, simplemente, obtendrás un resultado incorrecto :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias, Juanjo. Tu explicación ha sido de 10.

Te dejo un nuevo comentario, por si puedes resolverme una duda que me surge.